# Set tax amount magento 2.1 programmatically

Tags: magento2, php

I want to set my calculated tax amount in cart, review etc., in Magento 2.1. I dont know how to set tax amount programmatically. kindly help me out!!

Comment: if you get answer than please post it as am answer

Comment: @Murali, did you found any solution?